# ServiceStack Model Binder for ServiceBase derived types

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to use a custom model binder in ServiceStack? (Something similar to ASP.NET MVC model binding.)

I am trying to POST this object from JavaScript in JSON format and as a response I get HTTP Error 400 Bad request.

```
  var order = {
  Id: 1,
  TableId: 2,
  StationId: 3,
  OrderState: 4,
  OrderProducts: [{
      Id: 5,
      OrderId: 6,
      ProductId: 3,
      Name: '8',
      Quantity: 9,
      Price: 10,
      Comment: '11',
      OrderExtras: []
  }]
};
```

In C# I have:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TableId { get; set; }
    public long StationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderState { get; set; }
    public OrderProduct[] OrderProducts { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

If I send the request without the OrderProducts array everything works fine.

Also, if I use the IRestClient to internally test the request/response it also works.

Update:

I am not sure if I have described it correctly with the C# code.

If I sent this object from JavaScript, it works:

```
var order = {
  id:1,
  OrderDate: '',
  OrderState : 1,
  TableId: 2,
  StationId: 4
 }
```

..while this doesn't:

```
  var order = {
  id:1,
  OrderDate: '',
  OrderState : 1,
  TableId: 2,
  StationId: 4, 
  OrderProducts : [

      {id:1,
      OrderId: 1,
      ProductId: 2,
      Name:'t535',
      Quantity: 3,
      Price:3,
      Comment:'235235'},

      {id:1,
      OrderId: 1,
      ProductId: 2,
      Name:'t535',
      Quantity: 3,
      Price:3,
      Comment:'235235'}
  ] 
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTTP traffic? i.e. via Web Inspector or Fiddler. I want to make sure you're actually sending JSON and not url-encoded form data.

Comment: @mythz Unfortunately I could not copy paste the Fiddler output here so I pasted it at this url: http://pastebin.com/S8eKc9RS (I am not expert on Fiddler, I hope this is the info you wanted on what is being sent.) Thank you!

Comment: Hi, this is great for the HTTP Response, but I need to see the HTTP Request that generated this error. I can tell from the stack trace that it's trying to read a url-formencoded POST or QueryString that isn't formatted correctly.